# Создание фильтра в Django

Tags: python, django, django-filter

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу по написанию фильтра в Джанго:

"Нужно написать фильтр uglify, который преобразует текст по такому принципу: каждый нечётный символ переводится в нижний регистр, а чётный — в верхний.

**Пример вызова фильтра:**
{{ "Привет мир!!"|uglify }}

**Пример результата:**
пРиВеТ МиР!!

Я понимаю, что нужно фильтром пройтись по всем символам переменной, а также включить условие, которое будет проверять четность символа if x % 2 == 0.

Пока что получилось что-то вроде этого (но я, конечно, понимаю, что код не совсем верный):

```
@register.filter

def uglify(value):
    for i in value:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            i.upper()
        else:
            i.lower()             
    return value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки в питоне не изменяемые. Поэтому тебе в цикле нужно собрать новую строку.

Если модифицировать твой код, получится как-то так:

```
@register.filter

def uglify(value):
    uglify_str = ""
    for i in value:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            uglify_str = uglify_str + i.upper()
        else:
            uglify_str = uglify_str + i.lower()     
    return uglify_str
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если ответ помог - отметьте его как "верный" нажал на галочку слева от ответа. А также, если считаете ответ хорошим - проголосуйте за него нажав на стрелку вверх опять же слева от ответа. Это основная мотивация людей, которые помогают на этом ресурсе (имхо)

Answer (score 0):

```py
@register.filter
def uglify(value: str):
    return ''.join(list(map(lambda x: x[1].upper() if x[0] % 2 else x[1].lower(), enumerate(value))))
```

Не претендую на лучший ответ, но любителям компактности пойдет

`enumerate(value)` будет возвращать по очереди номер и элемент под этим номером

`map(func, iterable)` проходится по всем элементам из `iterable` (пронумерованные элементы строки) и применяет к ним функцию `func`

`lambda x: x[1].upper() if x[0] % 2 else x[1].lower()` лямбда-функция для `map`, возвращает верхний/нижний регистр в зависимости от номера элемента

Так как `map` возвращает генератор - преобразуем в список через `list()` и объединяем символы в строку, через `''.join()`

Comment: Супер, заработало, спасибо!))